# I need to impute the missing values of a categorical variable based on the values in second categorical variable using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Impute the missing values in first categorical variable(values- [0,1]) in such a way that if the values in second categorical variable(values- [1, 2, 3]) is either 2 or 3 then set the missing value in that  row for first column to be 1 else set it to 0.

problem-

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| NaN | 3 |
| NaN | 2 |
| NaN | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |

Expected-

| Col A | Col B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace missing values by `1` if `2,3` tested by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and converted to integers for `True, False` to `1,0` mapping:

```
df['Col A'] = df['Col A'].fillna(df['Col B'].isin([2,3]).astype(int))
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain how the mapping worked in this.

Comment: @Kashik Sharma it means isvpossible convert true and false to 1, 0 by astype function.